# How to set my Apache camel log level to ERROR Using logback.xml

Tags: java, logging, apache-camel, logback, slf4j

I am working on performance testing of **Apache camel**, so far i am able to run ***logback async*** to gain some speed,

Is there anyway to disable even the **INFO** of camel-context at starting my route.

**logback.xml:**

And my logback.xml configuration is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration debug="false" scan="false">
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.NopStatusListener" />

    <!-- To show the log in console -->
    <appender name="OUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <prudent>true</prudent>
        <encoder>
            <Pattern>
                %d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache.catalina.core" level="INFO" />

    <!-- DEBUG Config -->
    <logger name="logs_debug" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="OUT" />
    </logger>

    <!-- INFO Config -->
    <logger name="logs_info" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="OUT" />
    </logger>

    <!-- ERROR Config -->
    <logger name="logs_error" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="OUT" />
    </logger>

    <!-- To make the Logback ASYNC -->
    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
        <queueSize>500</queueSize>
        <discardingThreshold>2</discardingThreshold>
        <appender-ref ref="OUT" />
    </appender>

    <!-- root Logback -->
    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

***And i get this response.***

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO]                                                                         
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building roi-asynlogback 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Deleting /home/bizruntime/BizRuntime/Maven/log4j/roi-customlogback/target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 2 resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Compiling 7 source files to /home/bizruntime/BizRuntime/Maven/log4j/roi-customlogback/target/classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/bizruntime/BizRuntime/Maven/log4j/roi-customlogback/src/test/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Not compiling test sources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Tests are skipped.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Building jar: /home/bizruntime/BizRuntime/Maven/log4j/roi-customlogback/target/roi-customlogback-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] >>> camel-maven-plugin:2.13.2:run (default-cli) @ roi-customlogback >>>
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 2 resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/bizruntime/BizRuntime/Maven/log4j/roi-customlogback/src/test/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Not compiling test sources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] <<< camel-maven-plugin:2.13.2:run (default-cli) @ roi-customlogback <<<
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- camel-maven-plugin:2.13.2:run (default-cli) @ roi-customlogback ---
    [INFO] Using org.apache.camel.spring.Main to initiate a CamelContext
    [INFO] Starting Camel ...
    Jun 01, 2016 5:26:05 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@47262043: startup date [Wed Jun 01 17:26:05 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
    Jun 01, 2016 5:26:05 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [/home/bizruntime/BizRuntime/Maven/log4j/roi-customlogback/target/classes/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]
    Jun 01, 2016 5:26:06 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
    INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5918a58d: defining beans [logFormatter,log,addempdetails,customlogback,template,consumerTemplate,camel-1:beanPostProcessor,camel-1]; root of factory hierarchy
    Jun 01, 2016 5:26:07 PM org.restlet.engine.connector.ServerConnectionHelper start
    INFO: Starting the internal [HTTP/1.1] server on port 9090
```

Comment: what you want to disable ? are you want some thing like INFO log should be ON and ERROR should be OFF  ? or vice-versa ?

Comment: HI vishal,

I just want ERROR logs, i do not what any INFO logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I do not think so as you are starting Camel using the camel-maven-plugin that is a Maven plugin that has its own kind of startup and logging that happens before Camel is started etc.

If you want to have no logging at all, then start Camel yourself as a java main app.

Now the point is that you should really not waste time on this, as the startup is neglible and should not be measured in your performance tests. Its only when the application is up and running you may need to tweak/tune logging/JMX/threads and whatnot for higher performance.

Comment: Hi Claus,

Its like dream come true when you took time to read my post and reply.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

Try to look at the [link](http://camel.apache.org/log.html) from camels site.

The log gives some options:
Logging level to use. Possible values: ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, OFF

can be used like this:

```
.log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "some error to log")
```

Comment: My question is while running the camel context, we get some log of INFO level right? How to disable it?


once my camel context is started all logs will be error level. because i am using this configuration in logback.
 <!-- root Logback -->
 <root level="ERROR">
  <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
 </root>

Answer (score 2):

I have log4j with following configuration and working well for me

```
<logger name="org.apache.camel" additivity="false">
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <appender-ref ref="MYAPPENDER1" />
</logger>
<root level="ERROR"> <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" /> </root>
```

I think it is going to be something like this for logback too.

Comment: Hi RamPrakash,

its not working for me.

I am changing the question by adding my logback.xml please look at it once.

Comment: can you share your whole configuration file?